# Removing Quotes and escaped quotes from string value

Tags: c#, .net, string, escaping

I'm having a really embarrasing moment, as this feels like it's super simple but I just cannot seem to figure out what the best solution is, (or one at all for that matter).

I have a string like so:`"\"123456\""`

I want 123456

In C#, what is the quickest and easiest way of getting just the value from this? I've looked into using the Regex class and tried the `.Unescape()` method but I seem to have no success. Please help.

Comment: string.replace()

Comment: Or `string.Trim('\"')`

Answer (score 0):

@CharlieFace's answer was the answer that worked for me.

string.Trim('\ "')

Thank you!